# Getting variables from an array in MVC 4 and sending to controller via jQuery ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, variables, html-helper

I'm iterating through an array in my MVC 4 view using a foreach:

```
@model dynamic
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="row">
                <td>@Html.Label("", (string)item.DisplayName)</td>
                <td><a href="@Url.Action(item.ViewName, "Reporting", new { @name = "SendToFilter", ReportItemId = item.ReportItemId, MimeType = item.MimeType })" alt="A Link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" id="btnOpen" data-edit-id="OpenDocument" title="@Text.Get(Text.eTextType.Button, "Open")"></span></a></td>
            </tr>
        }
```

As you can see above I'm sending my variables across in the url.  I really don't want to do this so I have this function:

```
function SendToFilter() {
         $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ReportListing", "Reporting", null)",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'UReportFileName': UReportFileName },
        success: function (result) {
            // Send the user to correction action method of controller
            var link = '@Url.Action("ReportListing", "Reporting", null)';
            window.location.href = link;
        }
    });
    };
```

Id rather use:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="SendToFilter()" alt="A Link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" id="btnOpen" data-edit-id="OpenDocument" title="@Text.Get(Text.eTextType.Button, "Open")"></span></a></td>
```

and send the variables behind the scenes with an ajax post request, but ReportItemId and MimeType come from the controller and I get them in the foreach loop.  How can I best access these variables from the javascript function?  I really didn't want to attach the variables to the link tag.  Is this something that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you build the correct `href` value for your link in your razor markup, you can use the same value when making the ajax call.

Add a css class to the anchor tags so that we can use it later for our jQuery selection.

```
<td>
    <a class="ajaxLink" 
         href="@Url.Action(item.ViewName, "Reporting", new { @name = "SendToFilter", 
         ReportItemId = item.ReportItemId, MimeType = item.MimeType })" 
         alt="A Link">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" data-edit-id="OpenDocument"
            title="@Text.Get(Text.eTextType.Button, "Open")"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

And in your javascript, listen to the click event on anchor tag with the css class `ajaxLink`

```
$(function(){

   $("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default click behaviour

     $.post($(this).attr("href"),function(response){
        //do something with the response
       // reload to some other page
       // window.location.href="@Url.Action("ReportListing","Report")";
     });

   });    

});
```

If you do not wish to keep the items in the href value for any reasons, you may keep those in html 5 data attributes of the anchor tag and read them in the click event and append it to the url before making the `$.post` call.

```
<td>
    <a class="ajaxLink" 
         href="@Url.Action(item.ViewName, "Reporting")" 
         data-name="SendToFilter" data-reportitemid="@item.ReportItemId" 
         data-mime="@item.MimeType" 
         alt="A Link"> Link Text </a>
</td>
```

And in the click event,read the data attributes and append to the url

```
$(function(){

   $("a.ajaxLink").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();  // prevent the default click behaviour
     var _this=$(this);
     var myUrl=_this.attr("href");
     myUrl+="?name="+_this.data("name");
     myUrl+="&reportItemId="+_this.data("reportitemid");
     myUrl+="&MimeType="+_this.data("mime");
     alert(myUrl);

     $.post(myUrl,function(response){
        //do something with the response
       // reload to some other page
       // window.location.href="@Url.Action("ReportListing","Report")";
     });

   });    

});
```

Comment: But doesn't this still attach the variables to the tag which means they are on the page?  This is what I was trying to avoid if possible and it may not be possible.  If not, I do like this solution.

Comment: You can keep those variables in HTML 5 data attributes of the anchor tag and read them and append to the url before making the $.post call if you want.  See my edit in the answer.

Comment: This code isn't working.  My variables are showing up as undefined for some reason.

Comment: I think something in my application is clashing with this code because it works fine in JSFiddle.

Comment: my bad ! Use lowercase characters for data attributes. I updated the answer. Here is a working sample.http://jsbin.com/nexora/edit?html,js,output

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that with this methodology, I'm technically sending the data as a request and if the request is successful, then the window.location.href fires and redirects to the page.  The problem with this is that the data is now gone because I didn't use it when I did the post.  Is there another way of accomplishing this feet without an ajax post?

Comment: Do you want to send all those data to the new page with window.location.href redirect ?

Comment: Sure. use the same url we built (myUrl) as the window.location.href value.

Comment: Yes, but then aren't you just sending the variables in the url which is what I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: Your original requirement was to send data via ajax. But now you want to do a redirect with the values and at the same time you do not want to do that. Sorry i am confused what you really want.

Comment: I want to send data to the actionmethod of the view I am sending the user to, but I don't want the variables sent in the url.  I want a clean url and vars get sent in the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98865/discussion-between-shyju-and-jeff-mcbride).